# C# and XML: Why is XMLNS attirubute set to all child nodes?

Tags: c#, xml

Here is what I have attempted:
Creating elements:

```
            XmlNode xHeader = xDoc.CreateElement("Customer");
            XmlNode xCustomerID = xDoc.CreateElement("Customer_ID", strListName);
            XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Full_Name");
            XmlNode xEmail = xDoc.CreateElement("Email");
            XmlNode xHomeAddress = xDoc.CreateElement("Home_Address");
            XmlNode xMobileNumber = xDoc.CreateElement("Mobile_Number");
```

Appending nodes to document.

```
           xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xHeader);
            xHeader.AppendChild(xCustomerID);
            xCustomerID.AppendChild(xEmail);
            xCustomerID.AppendChild(xHomeAddress);
            xCustomerID.AppendChild(xMobileNumber);
```

This is what the is generated in the XML. http://pastebin.com/dNs8Ueiw
I want there to be no xmlns = "" in the child nodes of Customer_ID.

Comment: How are you getting the generated XML?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hBLxYv8c

Answer (score 2):

If you want XML of:

```
<Customer_ID xmlns="a">
  <Email>
  </Email>
  <Home_Address>
  </Home_Address>
  <Mobile_Number>
  </Mobile_Number>
</Customer_ID>
```

... then you need to make sure your `Email`, `Home_Address` and `Mobile_Number` elements are all in the same namespace as your `Customer_ID` element:

```
XmlNode xCustomerID = xDoc.CreateElement("Customer_ID", strListName);
XmlNode xEmail = xDoc.CreateElement("Email", strListName);
XmlNode xHomeAddress = xDoc.CreateElement("Home_Address", strListName);
XmlNode xMobileNumber = xDoc.CreateElement("Mobile_Number", strListName);
```

Basically you're seeing the result of namespace defaulting - unless an `xmlns=...` is specified for an element, it inherits the namespace of its parent.

(Also note that if you can, you should use LINQ to XML - it's a much more pleasant XML API, with nicer namespace handling.)

Comment: @user3680289: Well look how you've specified the namespace URI for `Customer_ID`... (I've edited my answer to show this, but it's important that you *understand* what's going on.)

Comment: Also, is there a way to change the XMLNS name? for example "ID" instead of "XMNLS"?

Comment: @user3680289: Yes, you specify it as an attribute instead of a namespace URI. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, to be honest - but I think you should read up more about XML, and the purpose of namespaces.